# Index was outside the bounds of the array about bitmap

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, indexing

I have code which convert byte array to bitmap.. (In my Project I cannot use MemoryStream or others bitmap converter.)

Here is my code.

```
public static Bitmap ConvertBitMap(int width, int height, byte[] imageData)
        {
            var data = new byte[width * height * 4];
            int o = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < width * height ; i++)
            {
                var value = imageData[i];


                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = 0;
            }
           ...
           ...
           ..
           ..
}
```

When I run application i says **"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."**

Here is arrayData information :

```
data   ------>     {byte[614400]}

imageData --->     {byte[105212]}
```

Could you please anyone help me about fixing this issue ? How can i handle this outside bounds problem ?

Comment: Every single time you do o++ it increments. You are going to go outside of data range. You're attempting to access data[o^4]

Comment: @AMR but imageData is 6 times bigger than data ? .. So how can i solve it should i delete o++  ?

Comment: After each o++ write out the value of o and see what size it is when it finally explodes.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that data is 6x imageData, not the 4x that you set. I think that imageData is not equal to width*height... I think that the exception is happening when accessing imageData[i] not data[o++]

Comment: It think my ImageData overs at 105.212 but i is incrementing up to 153.600 .... So here is the problem i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the length of `imageData` is less than `height * width`.  Hence you eventually get an exception on this line because `i` is greater than `imageData.Length`

```
var value = imageData[i];
```

Consider the sizes that you posted in the question

- data : 614400
- imageData : 105212

The size of `data` was calculated as `height * width * 4` hence we can calculate `height * width` by dividing by `4` and we end up with `height * width == 153600`.  This is clearly larger than `105212` and hence you end up accessing outside the bounds of the array

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but the issue is that imageData size is not equal to `width*height`

This code should fix it (though it might not be what you're looking for it to do)

```
public static Bitmap ConvertBitMap(int width, int height, byte[] imageData)
        {
            var data = new byte[imageData.Length * 4];
            int o = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < imageData.Length ; i++)
            {
                var value = imageData[i];


                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = 0;
            }
           ...
           ...
           ..
           ..
}
```